# Magento 2 Checkout that would better fit the order flow for a flower shop?

Tags: checkout

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
extensions from Amasty including their One-step Checkout
```

I have a flower shop/gift shop and the default Magento checkout does not really fit our needs. We purchased and tried the One-step checkout from Amasty but this does not work for our customers either! The main problem is that customers tend to forget to fill in one of the addresses - in our scenario, **the Delivery/Shipping address and Billing address will always be different** because customer A is order a flower/present to be delivered to person B. We've tried to force customers to have to confirm the address by selecting it from a list of addresses and clicking an UPDATE button but many customers are just not smart enough to figure this out it seems. I think the only way will be to break this down into simple to understand steps such as:

Step 3: WHO are you sending this TO (Delivery address)? Name, address, phone etc.

Step 4. What is YOUR Billing address? Name, address, phone etc.

Step 5. Payment

and so on.

Are there any Checkouts already made that would fit this logic and if so, can you point me in the right direction? I am not looking for the steps exactly as I laid them out up above but just anything really that would make sense for a flower shop/gift shop customer where ALL customers order something for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify the magento's default checkout module. So that It could work like you want. It's a different approach to checkout. I think you should talk to Amasty and tell them about your functionality. They would definately help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. We had a really bad experience with Amasty and their extensions so I don't think we'll be doing that. If we were to hire someone to do a custom job, it definitely wold NOT be Amasty for us. Surely though there must be ready made solutions for this as we cannot be the only flowers shop or a gift shop out there?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your needs of a multiple-step checkout process which best suits your business.

With that being said, you did not need any kinds of One Step Checkout extension. What you'll need is, a Multi-Step Checkout extension, or having someone do the customization of adding more checkout steps for you.

This is one extension that I could find that probably does the job.

https://marketplace.magento.com/webkul-module-customcheckoutsteps.html

No reviews just yet but it's from Webkul, they're reliable enough really.

Your scenario is very interesting, I would definitely love to try to get my hands on and help you do the customization, but I'm afraid it's not possible on my side for now.

Please kindly review my answer, if you wish to discuss further, please let us continue down in the comment section.

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I helped one of my friend and my client. It is not 100% solution but we achieved big improve. Check it out.
Https://cranfordflorist.com

I customized this website from scratch. Send me a message if you like